# Is there a way to move a placeholder?

Tags: html, css, placeholder

I have some code:

```
<div class="txt-input">
<input id="txt-enter" type="text" placeholder="Enter To-Do">
</div>
```

But the placeholder is stuck to the left of the border.
I want to have it 10px to the right, how do you do that?
I do have a CSS file as well.

I tried ::placeholder but that didn't work. I also tried margin-left: 10px; put that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in using ::placeholder, you just need to using padding-left and not margin-left

```
#txt-enter::placeholder {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `::placeholder` selector to set css for placeholder of input or textare.

```css
input::placeholder {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input name="test_placeholder" placeholder="test placeholder" />
```